# How to save custom data in sales_flat_creditmemo table prgramatically Magento 1

Tags: database, magento, magento-1.9

I have created a new field in sales_flat_creditmemo table. Please help me in saving the custom data to a newly created field in the table in magento 1. I have tried this but its not saving the data. I'm trying to save the data using sales_order_creditmemo_save_after observer event

```
$creditMemos = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_creditmemo_collection');
$creditMemos->addFieldToFilter('increment_id', $incrementId);
$creditMemos->load();

foreach ($creditMemos as $creditMemo) {
    $creditMemo->setRefundtype('test');
    $creditMemo->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use :

```
saveAttribute();
```

another one :

```
$test='test'
->setData('refundtype', $test);
```

and one more question :
What`s the name of your database column that you created ?

`refundtype` ?
 or

`refund_type` ??

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried all the available methods including the methods you mentioned above and unable save the data. @alexey boltynov